# Is it possible to reset qupzilla settings?

Tags: lubuntu, qupzilla

I am currently using Lubuntu 18.04 and I've installed qupzilla, named falkon.

I've set my configurations but I am not able to put my favorites after exported in my tool bar.

My question is, How can I make my  exported favorites appear in my tool bar or at least...

Is it possible to reset qupzilla settings?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I was able to move my exported favorites folder to my toolbar, but It would be very usefull to know how to reset falkon configurations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean install would do just fine, uninstall and remove configuration files using

`sudo apt purge qupzilla`

Cleanup dependencies

`sudo apt autoremove`

and install qupzilla

`sudo apt install qupzilla`

Comment: No... that's the first think I did but when I install it again... it remembers my last configuration...

Comment: Do you mean to remove all your favorites and bookmarks?

Comment: No, I´ve tried to purge qupzilla but it doesn't remove falkon and I don't mean remove all favorites and bookmarks but to place its in my toolbar or at least reset my configurations in order to check if I am able to do it that way

Comment: I've found a solution... From editting bookmarks I was able to move my favorites folders  to toolbar favorites and suddenly it appears again...

Comment: I uninstall Falkon from software center, purge qupzilla and then autoremove, it works this way, thanks... @sudo